# How do I set up an RTMP stream server and URL endpoint?

Tags: video, streaming, rtmp

I've got a Haivision Barracuda, which can stream RTMP to a URL (secured by username/password) set in its interface, but have very little experience of streaming video. What software do I need (Windows or Linux, but ideally free or open source at the moment) to set up a server that can provide this URL on which to receive the stream, please?

Can I then rebroadcast that (also as RTMP, to a remote URL endpoint), and how can I view the live stream to test that it's working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we had the free version of Adobe Flash Media Server installed on a Linux server that could receive the stream and show it via players connecting to the URL and the inbuilt test applications. We didn't have time to take down one of our servers to test the Windows Streaming Media path, but thanks for the suggestion, AJ Henderson.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows server, Windows Streaming Media Services works nicely and is included with most versions of Windows Server.  You just need to install the role and then configure a publishing point for the URL.  Their is a GUI provided for doing the configuration.